# Why does many books and websites says that Tk() is a method when Tk is a class and Tk() is a constructor?

Tags: tkinter, tk-toolkit

I have seen the python documentation and there is no method called Tk(). Tk is a class and Tk() must be a constructor. I am learning python but I am familiar with object oriented programming and Python general naming rules. I need a confirmation about this. Please help.

Comment: But a constructor is a method, just a special one?!

Comment: what documentation have you seen that claims `Tk()` is a function?

Comment: Please post a link to the documentation that claims so

Answer (score 1):

The tkinter package provides a class named `Tk`. It is not a method. To create an instance of the class you call the class as if it were a function: `Tk()`. That causes the `__init__` method of the class to execute.

I don't think I've seen any tkinter documentation that makes a claim that `Tk()` is a function, so I can't comment on why they would.